# Dynamically Flatten JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have JSON that needs to be converted/flattened as given in the below expected JSON.

Below given input is sample data only, in actual scenario the input json will change. This logic will go the common -.dll(library) that will be used to bind the data to the data grid.

Input payload structure has the following hierarchy

- `Students` -> `Subjects` -> `Marks`
- `Students` can have multiple `Subjects`
- `Subjects` can have multiple `Marks`

#### Input

```json
[
   {
      "student":"Bob",
      "subjects":[
         {
            "subjectname":"English",
            "marks":[
               {
                  "type":"essay",
                  "grade":"A"
               },
               {
                  "type":"vocabulary",
                  "grade":"B"
               },
               {
                  "type":"spoken",
                  "grade":"C"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "subjectname":"French",
            "marks":[
               {
                  "type":"essay",
                  "grade":"B"
               },
               {
                  "type":"vocabulary",
                  "grade":"A"
               },
               {
                  "type":"spoken",
                  "grade":"B"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "student":"Mark",
      "subjects":[
         {
            "subjectname":"Dutch",
            "marks":[
               {
                  "type":"essay",
                  "grade":"C"
               },
               {
                  "type":"vocabulary",
                  "grade":"B"
               },
               {
                  "type":"spoken",
                  "grade":"A"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "subjectname":"Mandrian",
            "marks":[
               {
                  "type":"essay",
                  "grade":"C"
               },
               {
                  "type":"vocabulary",
                  "grade":"C"
               },
               {
                  "type":"spoken",
                  "grade":"C"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

#### Expected Output

```json
[
   {
      "student":"Bob",
      "subjectname":"English",
      "type":"essay",
      "grade":"A"
   },
   {
      "student":"Bob",
      "subjectname":"English",
      "type":"vocabulary",
      "grade":"B"
   },
   {
      "student":"Bob",
      "subjectname":"English",
      "type":"spoken",
      "grade":"C"
   },
   {
      "student":"Bob",
      "subjectname":"French",
      "type":"essay",
      "grade":"B"
   },
   {
      "student":"Bob",
      "subjectname":"French",
      "type":"vocabulary",
      "grade":"A"
   },
   {
      "student":"Bob",
      "subjectname":"French",
      "type":"spoken",
      "grade":"B"
   },
   ...
]
```

**Code**

```
public static void Flatten(string json)
{
    JObject jObject = new JObject(); 
    JToken input = JToken.Parse(json); 
    FillJarrayFromJToken(jObject, input, "");
}

public static void FillJarrayFromJToken(JObject obj, JToken token, string propName)
{
    switch (token.Type)
    {
        case JTokenType.Object:
            foreach (JProperty prop in token.Children<JProperty>())
            {
                FillJarrayFromJToken(obj, prop.Value, prop.Name);
            }
            break;
        case JTokenType.Array:
            foreach (JToken value in token.Children())
            {
                FillJarrayFromJToken(obj, value, propName);
            }
            break;
        default: obj.Add(new JProperty(propName, token.ToString())); 
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try? What language are you using? There is not enough information to answer the question.

Comment: Did tried using C#,

Comment: Which json serializer library are you using? Could you please share with us your code and highlight where did you get stuck?

Comment: using Newtonsoft

Comment: public static void Flatten(string json)
{JObject jObject = new JObject();JToken input = JToken.Parse(json);FillJarrayFromJToken(jObject, input, "");}
public static void FillJarrayFromJToken(JObject obj, JToken token, string propName)
{switch (token.Type){
case JTokenType.Object:
foreach (JProperty prop in token.Children<JProperty>()){
 FillJarrayFromJToken(obj, prop.Value, prop.Name);}
break;
case JTokenType.Array:
foreach (JToken value in token.Children()){
FillJarrayFromJToken(obj, value, propName);}
break;
default:
obj.Add(new JProperty(propName, token.ToString()));
break;
}}

Comment: You can edit the post to add the code there :) (In this case I have done it for you)

Having said that. This is for general (unkown) Json input and not something that can be done with interface/object mapping?

Comment: Thanks @Me.Name , Yes it will be an unknown JSON.

Comment: And were did you get stuck with your code?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't resist having a go at it. It is very situation specific of course and I must admit I haven't really tested it extensively, for example, what happens with sub collections that are not nested, but are in the same class. And no check for double names, but it works for the given example.

The idea is, not creating an object until you are at the end of the line of collections, instead of creating an object and starting adding properties to it.

```
public static JToken Flatten(string json)
{
    JToken input = JToken.Parse(json); 
    var res= new JArray();
    foreach(var obj in GetFlattenedObjects(input))
        res.Add(obj);
    return res;
}

public static IEnumerable<JToken> GetFlattenedObjects(JToken token, IEnumerable<JProperty> OtherProperties = null)
{
if (token is JObject obj)
{
    var children = obj.Children<JProperty>().GroupBy(prop => prop.Value?.Type == JTokenType.Array).ToDictionary(gr=>gr.Key);
    if(children.TryGetValue(false, out var directProps))
        OtherProperties = OtherProperties?.Concat(directProps) ?? directProps; //NB, no checks if any sub collection contains duplicate prop names
    
    if (children.TryGetValue(true, out var ChildCollections))
    {
        foreach (var childObj in ChildCollections.SelectMany(childColl => childColl.Values()).SelectMany(childColl => GetFlattenedObjects(childColl,OtherProperties)))
            yield return childObj;
    }
    else //no (more) child properties, return an object
    {
        var res = new JObject();
        if (OtherProperties != null)
            foreach (var prop in OtherProperties)
                res.Add(prop);
        yield return res;
    }
}
else if (token is JArray arr)
{
    foreach (var co in token.Children().SelectMany(c=>GetFlattenedObjects(c,OtherProperties)))
        yield return co;
}
    else 
        throw new NotImplementedException(token.GetType().Name);

    
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, Had tested with multiple samples it is working well without issues for all happy paths.  Thanks a ton @Me.Name.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a generic solution then you can achieve the desired output quite easily with [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm)

```
var semiParsedData = JArray.Parse(rawData);
var flattenedData =
    from student in semiParsedData
    from subject in student["subjects"]
    from mark in subject["marks"]
    select new
    {
        student = student["student"],
        subjectname = subject["subjectname"],
        type = mark["type"],
        grade = mark["grade"]
    };

string serializedFlattenedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(flattenedData);
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, i need a generic solution.

Comment: What is a generic solution to this? You haven't specified what will be common, you've just said "the structure could be different", which doesn't give us enough information to suggest a generic solution. Are you looking to flatten any JSON with a similar structure (parent - child - grandchild) or are you looking to flatten absolutely any JSON structure?